# Android NullPointerException when getting LocationManager from service context

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, locationmanager

I'm getting:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.getSystemService(ContextWrapper.java:423)
```

when the app:

```
    locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
```

The code which throws the exceptions is:

```
421:    @Override
422:    public void grantUriPermission(String toPackage, Uri uri, int modeFlags) {
423:        mBase.grantUriPermission(toPackage, uri, modeFlags);
424:    }
```

(The debugger shows `mBase` as being null in the call.)

I have checked:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

and debugged:

```
context={MyService@830033501600}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: check if `context!=null` then  `context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);`

Comment: put your service class code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have to use Activity context to get Location Manager.

Was your `context` an application context? Try changing it to Activity.

Edit:

If you are in Service, run `getSystemService` in `onCreate()`

Comment: No, my context is a class which `extends Service`.

Comment: How can I get an application context from a long running service which starts from a BootReceiver?

Comment: are you calling it in the constructor? you should call the command in onCreate()

Comment: Thanks, the problem was that I was calling it (indirectly) from a parameter initialiser in the service.  Calling it (indirectly) from the service's `onCreate()` fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow you need to extend Activity class where you will use getSystemService method